# How to build xlsx file from html in c# without using Microsoft libraries?

Tags: c#, excel

I have a system that outputs html files in a excel format.
I need to convert these files to .xlsx files so I would be able to work on them with ClosedXML.

The thing Is that my code is supposed to run on a server that doesn't have any office installed on it, so I can't use any of Microsoft libraries.

Is it possible to convert html to xlsx like so ?

Comment: Can you recommend some ? as long as they don't need office to be installed...

Comment: I need to convert html to xlsx, this is not what you sent me...